# What's the Seminal Book on data science?

Tags: data, books

Can people provide the best textbook they have used for learning data science?  I know this is somewhat difficult because you have no basis of comparison but if you can just give your opinion on a book and why, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I don't think there's any such thing: first, data science is very broad and not so well defined. A more well defined domain is Machine Learning, but not everything in data science is ML. Second, data science (as well as ML) is recent and things change very fast: any general-purpose book is bound to become obsolete within a few years, so it's unlikely that any book can ever become a reference.

Comment: How could this question be answered with facts and citations?  I'm simply asking what are some respected textbooks on data science.  I'm sure it's a question that many people would like to know.  smh..

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out by the first comment, data science is a very broad field and not sharply defined.

But I think since you like to get started with data science and you're looking for resources, I share some of my recommendations with you (in no particular order).

- Very applied, less academical, with lots of code examples: **Hands-on Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras, and TensorFlow** by Aurélien Géron
- *The* Deep learning bible, more academical, great overview: **Deep Learning** by Ian Goodfellow, Yoshua Bengio and Aaron Courville
- A classic for Machine learning, covers a lot of topics, very educational with great explanations: **Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning** by Christopher M. Bishop
- If you're more into statistics: **An Introduction to Statistical Learning: with Applications in R** by James, Witten, Hastie & Tibshirani
- **Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective** by Kevin P. Murphy
- The classic RL reference: **Reinforcement Learning** by Richard S. Sutton & Andrew G. Barto

This is only a partial list focusing more on theory and classic data science algorithms. Keep in mind there are many many more books, e.g. I didn't mentioned any resources for Big Data, Data Analytics, Data Mining etc. whatever one would throw into the data science bucket. Further it's possible that this list might be outdated in a few years.